# change child JSP from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Assume I have a home.jsp made of

> /common/_header.jsp 
>   /_homebody.jsp 
>   /common/_footer.jsp

And search.jsp made of

> /common/_header.jsp 
>   /_searchbody.jsp 
>   /common/_footer.jsp

The header has a search box. On submitting a string, I want to move to search page, but would be prefer an ajax call. So what is the best way to display the search page. I have the following solution.

1. Remove the _homebody content using `$(selector).empty()` or `$(selector).remove()`
2. Add the _searchbody content using `$(selector).append(content)`

The removal part is fine, but the appending part is dirty and error prone as I need to store the HTML String in my javascript. Any work arounds? Two probable solutions could be

1. A better way of storing the HTML String in javascript
   OR
2. A method that can remove a child element of JSP and add a new one.

Or any better solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup your server to return the search results as a HTML, you can just use http://api.jquery.com/load/ to insert the generated results.

A way to go about this would be hiding the `_homebody` content and showing a div which you can just routinely update its content. Then after every search, replace the content with that of the `load`ed content

Comment: The first part of your answer brings client side stuff on to server, which is less desirable IMHO.

Comment: But I like the second part. Never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the html() function to replace the contents

in the ajax success

```
$(selector).html(content);
```